# objective-c - Get pointer to object's property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pointers

I have an object `Activity` which has three `NSString` properties `activityName, activityType, activityDescription`

I want to do something like this

```
NSString *currentProperty = activity.activityDescription;
currentProperty = @"My description";
```

and make `activity.activityDescription` be automatically updated as I change `currentProperty`

I think it should be possible since I work with pointers, but in practice it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what **Key-Value Coding** (KVC) was made for. Example:

```
NSString *currentKey = @"activityDescription";

NSString *oldDescription = [myActivity valueForKey:currentKey];
[myActivity setValue:@"My Description" forKey:currentKey];
```

You don't use a pointer (in the C sense of the word) but a key of type `NSString`. You can use KVC to get and set arbitrary properties of objects.

[Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1) has all the details.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is how I'm going to do it now :-)

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is the difference between:

1. Pointers
2. Pointers to pointers
3. Object contents

To do what you're thinking about would be a pointer to a pointer (though you generally don't want to do that). What you have is a pointer (`currentProperty`). So, when you set `currentProperty`, all you're doing is replacing your local pointer contents with a different address.

Generally you should just set `activity.activityDescription = ...` directly, or, use an `NSMutableString` if you want to change the string contents, or, as per the answer from @NikolaiRuhe, use KVC (as that allows you to abstract away from what the current key is).

Comment: Thank you for explanation! I am going to use KVC approach now

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not really working with pointers. activityDescription is a property, and a property is really the combination of two methods, a getter method named activityDescription and a setter method named setActivityDescription:. The thing that is the equivalent of a pointer is a "selector", type SEL. For example

```
SEL theSetter = @selector (setActivityDescription:);
[self performSelector:theSetter withObject:some string];
```

Or you can define a block, which is the equivalent of a pointer to arbitrary code.

Comment: Nice, but NB, this will fire a warning under ARC, while KVC or objc_msgSend() won't. . (not that obc_msgSend is safer - just assumes you know what you're doing, I guess).